# Ruby regex question wrt the sub method on String

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm running through the Koans tutorial (which is a great way to learn) and I've encountered this statement:

```
assert_equal __, "one two-three".sub(/(t\w*)/) { $1[0, 1] }
```

In this statement the __ is where I'm supposed to put my expected result to make the test execute correctly. I have stared at this for a while and have pulled most of it apart but I cannot figure out what the last bit means:

```
{ $1[0, 1] }
```

The expected answer is:

```
"one t-three"
```

and I was expecting:

```
"t-t"
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`{ $1[0, 1] }` is a block containing the expression `$1[0,1]`. `$1[0,1]` evaluates to the first character of the string `$1`, which contains the contents of the first capturing group of the last matched regex.

When `sub` is invoked with a regex and a block, it will find the first match of the regex, invoke the block, and then replace the matched substring with the result of the block.

So `"one two-three".sub(/(t\w*)/) { $1[0, 1] }` searches for the pattern `t\w*`. This finds the substring `"two"`. Since the whole thing is in a capturing group, this substring is stored in `$1`. Now the block is called and returns `"two"[0,1]`, which is `"t"`. So `"two"` is replaced by `"t"` and you get `"one t-three"`.

An important thing to note is that `sub`, unlike `gsub`, only replaces the first occurrence, not ever occurrence of the pattern.

Comment: perfect. thanks. I was mistakenly reading the regex as if it were of the s/.../.../ statement I'm used to. But if I understand correctly the second ...is actually the behavior in the block that was confusing me. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @jaydel: In perl `"one two-three" =~ s/(t\w*)/foo/` returns "one foo-three" as well, so I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: I made my question too difficult. I was thinking that it was matching to "two" and that where you've got // was the empty string, but in fact there was not that trailing / there, and the { $1[0, 1] } was what was to be substituted for the match. your explanation is solid and got me where I need to go. thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

@sepp2k already gave a really good answer, I just wanted to add how you could have used IRB to maybe get there yourself:

```
>> "one two-three".sub(/(t\w*)/) { $1 } #=> "one two-three"
>> "one two-three".sub(/(t\w*)/) { $1[0] } #=> "one t-three"
>> "one two-three".sub(/(t\w*)/) { $1[1] } #=> "one w-three"
>> "one two-three".sub(/(t\w*)/) { $1[2] } #=> "one o-three"
>> "one two-three".sub(/(t\w*)/) { $1[3] } #=> "one -three"
>> "one two-three".sub(/(t\w*)/) { $1[0,3] } #=> "one two-three"
>> "one two-three".sub(/(t\w*)/) { $1[0,2] } #=> "one tw-three"
>> "one two-three".sub(/(t\w*)/) { $1[0,1] } #=> "one t-three"
```

Answer (score 1):

Cribbing from the documentation (http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001185), here are answers to your two questions "why is the return value 'one t-three'" and "what does { $1[0, 1] } mean?"

**What does { $1[0, 1] } mean?**
The method String#sub can take either two arguments, or one argument and a block. The latter is the form being used here and it's just like the method Integer.times, which takes a block:

```
5.times { puts "hello!" }
```

So that explains the enclosing curly braces.

$1 is the substring matching the first capture group of the regex, as described [here](http://blog.purifyapp.com/2010/01/04/cryptic-ruby-global-variables-and-their-meanings/). [0, 1] is the string method "[]" which returns a substring based on the array values - here, the first character.

Put together, { $1[0, 1] } is a block which returns the first character in $1, where $1 is the substring to have been matched by a capture group when a regex was last used to match a string.

**Why is the return value 'one t-three'?**
The method String#sub ('substitute'), unlike its brother String#gsub ('globally substitute'), replaces the first portion of the string matching the regex with its replacement. Hence the method is going to replace the first substring matching "(t\w*)" with the value of the block described above - i.e. with its first character. Since 'two' is the first substring matching (t\w*) (a 't' followed by any number of letters), it is replaced by its first character, 't'.